# App Engine Search: How can I search multiple search indexes in parallel?

Tags: google-app-engine, search, task-queue

I have a lot of indexes, and currently it is slow because when a query comes in from the user, it sequentially goes through each of these results and then appends the results. 

`indexes = search.get_indexes(index_name_prefix=userDomain, limit=200)
domain_indexes = [index for index in indexes if userDomain==str(index.name).split(":")[0] ]
for index in indexes:
    response.append(responseListItem)`

This makes it really slow, the question is whether I can farm these out and do them in parallel, and then afterwards coalesce the results and send the response back to the user?

Comment: Yes, you can do them in parallel. What's the problem?

Comment: How do I coalesce the results back to send them in the response? Basically once I put them on the task-queue, the response.append stops working.

Comment: You cannot use a task queue if you need to respond to a user request. You need to make a bunch of async calls, as Dmitry suggests, wait for their results, merge the results and respond to a client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not *yet* documented features to make async calls in Search API, just like with datastore:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/search/search.py#3636

Comment: Thanks, any idea on how to upgrade the App Engine to this version? Seems like they have it @1.9.10?

Comment: It's already up to date in production, you are able to upgrade only local development server.

Comment: Yes, was wondering on localhost whether there was any way for me to upgrade the app engine libraries without downloading the 55 MB file at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

Comment: Well, you can *try* to download only required files from code.google.com repository.

Comment: Thanks, was able to update it on a faster connection. Will try this out.

Comment: Don't forgot to accept the answer if your problem is solved, so another people don't need to answer on it again.